# TikZ or symbol eyes for difficulty of examples/exercises

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-styles

In this time, very busy from June, I'm creating my book of Physics and I'm using some options of the `structure.tex` of [The Legrand Orange Book](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book). I have occurred of your precious help if possible. Into my old MWE (year 2007) with macros, I can put to add my eyes (erre.69, erre.70 etc.) in format `.eps` files. You can see picture below,

[image]

with my source,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,italian,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

%occhietti
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input epsf
\def\ob{\epsfxsize=.28cm\epsfbox{erre.69}}
\def\os{\epsfxsize=.28cm\epsfbox{erre.72}}
\def\od{\epsfxsize=.28cm\epsfbox{erre.73}}
\def\oa{\epsfxsize=.28cm\epsfbox{erre.74}}
\def\oc{\epsfxsize=.28cm\epsfbox{erre.75}}
\def\ov{\epsfxsize=.28cm\epsfbox{erre.76}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

Different typology of examples or exercises with macros
$\ob,\os, \od,\oa,\oc,\ov$


\end{document}
```

But I would like to have the same eyes (created with TikZ - I don't remember that exists a symbol for these eyes!) without to use images in `.pdf` or `.eps`. format. Infact into my book I'm using many reduce figures only in `.pdf`. 
The code below is the same into Legrand Orange Book to create "*examples*" (for example) is:

`\newenvironment{example}{\begin{exampleT}}{\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exampleT}}`.

Is the possibility to create a best `\newenvironment {example}` and `\newenvironment {exercise}` exactly to have the same eyes created with TikZ, same size, same command (`\ob`,`\os`,`\oa`, etc.)?

[image]

Comment: You don't need a tikz command for the square : `\square` will do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is very simple to do.

If you get the idea, you can create the other few you want.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\straightEye[1][1.2ex]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1/1cm]
  \draw (0,0) circle (.5);
  \fill (0,0) circle (.25);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand\downwardsEye[1][1.2ex]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1/1cm]
  \draw (0,0) circle (.5);
  \fill (0,-.25) circle (.25);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand\rightEye[1][1.2ex]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1/1cm]
  \draw (0,0) circle (.5);
  \fill (.25,0) circle (.25);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\straightEye \downwardsEye \ look at me \rightEye\rightEye
\end{document}
```

Or like this :

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\sideEye[2][1.2ex]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1/1cm]
  \draw (0,0) circle (.5);
  \fill (#2:.25) circle (.25);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ang in {0,30,...,360} {\sideEye{\ang}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot lot for your job (+1). I prefer the first code, using the `\newcommand`. I have add other newcommand at your code for upeye and blank eye (similar at the simbol `\circle`, colored ocre). Thanks again and my best regards Sebastiano. Is there a reason for a downvote for your opinion?

Comment: Thanks. Don't know about your downvote. I disagree with it and upvoted you in reaction. (Maybe someone thought it was not difficult enough to do for you to ask ?)

Comment: @Sebastiano You can maybe add a little bit of space between both eyes if you want to have exactly what you posted. Maybe a `\hspace{2pt}` or so, or a `\,` or another default space.

Comment: Your job was beautiful. I did not know some commands and learned something new. I believe that someone should have a pinch of humility and understanding the difficulties of others often when it hurries like me.

Comment: This is not the case. It's perfect for your work and I put it in my structure.tex. I also gave you the green check.

Comment: @Sebastiano I guess you're right. Maybe you should take it easy, it's just internet points, and only one person in more than 50 downvoted... `;)` not a huge deal !

Answer (score 3):

I like the answer of marsupilam. For the completeness sake: my idea of reducing the number of images embedded into the pdf file would be to embedd it only once.

Basically save each kind of eyes using a box, then just use these boxes. My current understanding is that the images would be embedded only once and then referenced again and again in the output file.

*Update:* I was just told than standard boxes don't work like this, but `xsavebox` does the trick. Thanks to AlexG.

Comment: No, the content of a standard `\savebox` is re-inserted on every `\usebox`, replicating the saved code in the output file (PDF, DVI, PS).  To save space, the `xsavebox` package can be used.

Comment: I haven't understood, but thanks for your answer. I have voted you.

Comment: The idea is to call a macro once, to save the image in the output file. Then you use other macro, that only references the _same_ image. This is not the standard behavior, normally on each call of a macro a new image is embedded.